# parsing from long text in file in c

Tags: c

```
<td>&nbsp;<a href="wtzresult.php?CiID=41832&forma=12h"> Asmara </a>&nbsp;</td><td width=``"100">Sun, 09:08 PM</td></tr><tr>
<td>&nbsp;<a href="wtzresult.php?CiID=42107&forma=12h"> Astana </a>&nbsp;</td><td width="100">Mon, 12:08 AM</td></tr><tr bgcolor="#E0E0E0">
<td>&nbsp;<a href="wtzresult.php?CiID=4698&forma=12h"> Asuncion </a>&nbsp;</td><td width="100">Sun, 03:08 PM<sup>dst</sup></td></tr><tr>
<td>&nbsp;<a href="wtzresult.php?CiID=3963&forma=12h"> Athens </a>&nbsp;</td><td width="100">Sun, 08:08 PM</td></tr><tr bgcolor="#E0E0E0">
```

I want to parse "Athens Sun, 08:08 PM" 
i'm testing 
and get line for use strtok
for parsing day an clock but return segmentation fault 
Thanx

```
while( fscanf(fp,"%s",word) != EOF){
    if (strstr(word,"Athens") != NULL)
        strcpy(p,word);
    }
```

Comment: What is `p`? and `word`? What is you current problem? Moreover: how is `fd` retrieved?

Comment: and the text in file

Comment: Edit your question: don't post additional things using comments.

Comment: Hint: use `fgets` instead if `fscanf`. This will save you a lot of trouble. And please show a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strstr()` to get a pointer to the begining of the Athens in your string and then loop through the characters and trimming all the characters between `'<'` and `'>'`, including themselves and compose a new string. This will leave you with the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `fscanf()`, read each line of your file with [`fgets(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets). In terms of finding `"Athens Sun, 08:08 PM"` in your file, you can use [`strstr(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html) to match `Athens"`, then you can parse the rest of the line with [`strtok(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html), with the html tags, `<` and `>`, as the delimeters.

You can then add these strings, using [`strcat(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) and [`strcpy(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html), to a dynamically allocated `char*` pointer. You need to make sure that this pointer can hold both `"Athens"` and `"Sun, 08:08 PM"`, plus a space and the `\0` null-terminator. You can also compare the strings found with [`strcmp(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp).

Here is an example of how you can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define LINESIZE 1024

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    char *ret, *token, *result;
    char line[LINESIZE] = {0};
    size_t numbytes, slen;

    const char *city = "Athens";
    const char *datetime = "Sun, 08:08 PM";
    const char *delim = "<>\n";
    const char *space = " ";

    fp = fopen("html.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    numbytes = strlen(city) + strlen(datetime) + 1;

    result = malloc(numbytes+1);
    if (!result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate string\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fgets(line, LINESIZE, fp) != NULL) {
        ret = strstr(line, city);
        if (ret != NULL) {
            token = strtok(ret, delim);
            while (token != NULL) {
                slen = strlen(token);
                for (int i = (int)slen-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (!isspace(token[i])) {
                        token[i+1] = '\0';
                        break;
                    }
                }   

                if (strcmp(token, city) == 0) {
                    strcpy(result, token);
                    strcat(result, space);
                }
                if (strcmp(token, datetime) == 0) {
                    strcat(result, token);
                }
                token = strtok(NULL, delim);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Extracted string: %s\n", result);

    free(result);
    result = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will give you some ideas.  Your segmentation faults are likely  coming from either overrunning an undersized buffer of dereferencing a null pointer (the p variable I'll guess).  Of course, if the format of the input deviates from your snippet, the code will be useless.  After you advance a bit in C, you might want to look at the expat library as well.  That would require converting the lines into little XML documents.  I'm sure that HTML parsing libraries for C exist, but I haven't tried them.

At least the result of this program was:
Athens Sun, 08:08 PM

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{       
   char buf[1024];
   FILE *fp = fopen("the-data-file.txt","r");
   if(!fp){ /* error handling */ }

   while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp)){
      char* city = strstr(buf,"Athens");
      char* td = city ? strstr(city, "<td") : NULL; 
      char* greater_than = td ? strstr(td, ">") : NULL; 
      char* less_than = greater_than ? strstr(greater_than, "<") : NULL; 
      if(less_than){
         while(*city && isalpha(*city)){
            printf("%c", *city++);
         }       
         printf(" ");
         while(++greater_than < less_than){
            printf("%c", *greater_than);
         }       
         printf("\n");
      }       
   }       


   fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot an obvious comment.  Try compiling with -g and running in a debugger to figure out where the crash happens.   Good luck.